# is there a large list of highly composite number?

Tags: number-theory

I'm searching for some very big {more less $2^{1024}$} highly composite number (HCN), for a number theory experiment, so I asked myself "if there are prime list this size, why not HCN lists this size" so instead of searching them, I could just copy them, but I have not found any list enough big, I have just found this list: https://oeis.org/A002182/list but is verry small.

I could work with a not so big list, but I still need lots of very big, very composite numbers

Comment: Is the *r* repeated for emphasis each time, or are you just mistaken about the spelling of the word *very*? Anyway OEIS also has the first 1000 entries of the list: https://oeis.org/A002182/b002182.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, had this; here are about 65 SHC numbers larger than $2^{996}$ I had the program put a blank line before the number if it is double the previous. The first four are below $2^{1024},$ the others are larger, and get much larger...

```
2536167501897096244709306448674533523279852832973804890524367612394680652633235086726188105424000657406729364457852941449795346842548126508969754339516210231616654201028670707444697226538742286219214636047772649884407032022127181313321413718927560216227999792415128535218878232596643671071696652800000

5072335003794192489418612897349067046559705665947609781048735224789361305266470173452376210848001314813458728915705882899590693685096253017939508679032420463233308402057341414889394453077484572438429272095545299768814064044254362626642827437855120432455999584830257070437756465193287342143393305600000
3342668767500372850526865899353035183682846033859474845711116513136189100170603844305115922948832866462069302355450176830830267138478430738822136219482365085270750236955787992412110944578062333236924890310964352547648468205163624970957623281546524364988503726403139409418481510562376358472496188390400000
2209504055317746454198258359472356256414361228381112873015048015183020995212769141085681625069178524731427808856952566885178806578534242718361432041077843321363965906627775862984405334366099202269607352495547437033995637483613156105802988989102252605257400963152475149625616278481730772950319980526054400000
1486996229228843363675427875924895760566865106700488963539127314218173129778193631950663733671557147144250915360729077513725336827353545349457243763645388555277949055160493155788504790028384763127445748229503425123879064026471654059205411589665816003338230848201615775698039755418204810195565346894034611200000
1006696447187926957208264672001154429903767677236231028315989191725703208859837088830599347695644188616657869699213585476792053032118350201582554027987928051923171510343653866468817742849216484637280771551373818808866126345921309798082063646203757434259982284232493880147572914418124656502397739847261431782400000
687573673429354111773244770976788475624273323552345792339820617948655291651268731671299354476124980825177325004562878880648972220936833187680884401115754859463526141564715590798202518366014859007262766969588318246455564294264254592090049470357166327599567900130793320140792300547579140391137656315679557907379200000
475113408339683691235312136744960836656372866574670942506816047002520806531026693584867853943002361750197531578152949306528439804667351732687491121170986607889296563821218473241557940190916267574018571975985527908300794927336599923134224184016801932371301418990378184217287479678377186010276120514134574513999027200000
333054499246118267555953807858217546496117379468844330697278048948767085378249712202992365614044655586888469636285217463876436303071813564613931275940861612130396891238674149742332116073832303569387018955165855063718857244062956546117091152995778154592282294712255107136318523254542407393203560480408336734313318067200000
236135639965497851697171249771476240465747222043410630464370136704675863533179045951921587220357660811103924972126219181888393338877915817311277274642070883000451395888219972167313470296347103230695396439212591240176669786040636191197017627474006711605928146950988870959649832987470566841781324380609510744628142509644800000
169781525135192955370266128585691416894872252649212243303882128290661945880355734039431621211437158123183722054958751591777754810653221472646808360467648964877324553643630159988298385143073567222869990039793853101687025576163217421470655674153810825644662337657760998219988229917991337559240772229658238225387634464434611200000
7979731681354068902402508043527496594058995874512975435282460029661111456376719499853286196937546431789634936583061324813554476100701409214399992941979501349234254021250617519450024101724457659474889531870311095779290202079671218809120816685229108805299129869914766916339446806145592865284316294793937196593218819828426726400000
5801264932344408092046623347644490023880890000770933141450348441563628028785875076393339065173596255911064598895885583139454104125209924498868794868819097480893302673449198936640167521953680718438244689669716166631543976911920976074230833730161562101452467415428035548178777828067846013061697946315192341923270082015266230092800000
4252327195408451131470174913823411187504692370565093992683105407666139345100046430996317534772246055582810350990684132441219858323778874657670826638844398453494790859638262820557242793592047966615233357527901950140921735076438075462411201124208425020364658615508750056815044147973731127574224594649035986629756970117190146658022400000
3142469797406845386156459261315500867565967661847604460592814896265276976028934312506278658196689835075696849382115573874061475301272588372018740886106010457132650445272676224391802424464523447328657451213119541154141162221487737766721877630790026090049482716860966291986317625352587303277351975445637594119390400916603518380278553600000
2334855059473286121914249231157417144601513972752770114220461467925100793189498194192165043040140547461242759090911871388427676148845533160409924478376765769649559280837598434723109201377140921365192486251347819077526883530565389160674355079676989384906765658627697954945833995636972366335072517756108732430707067881036414156546965324800000
1753476149664437877557601172599220275595736993537330355779566562411750695685313143838315947323145551143393312077274815412709184787782995403467853283260951093006819019909036424477055010234232831945259557174762212127222689531454607259666440664837419028064981009629401164164321330723366247117639460834837658055461007978658347031566770958924800000
1327381445295979473311104087657609748625972904107759079325131887745695276633782049885605172123621182215548737242497035267420852884351727520425164935428539977406161998071140573329130642747314253782561484781294994580307575975311137695567495583281926204245190624289456681272391247357588249068053071851972107147983983039844368702896045615906073600000
1010137279870240379189750210707441018704365380026004659366425366574474105518308139962945535986075719666032589041540243838507269044991664643043550515861118922806089280532137976303468419130706147128529289918565490875614065317211775786326864138877545841430590065084276534448289739239124657540788387679350773539615811093321564582903890713704522009600000
776795568220214851596917912034022143383656977239997583052781106895770587143578959631505117173292228423179060972944447511812089895598590110500490346697200451637882656729214103777367214311513027141839023947376862483347216228935855579685358522796832752060123760049808654990734809474886861648866270125420744851964558730764283164253091958838777425382400000
600462974234226080284417546002299116835566843406518131699799795630430663861986535795153455574954892571117414132086057926630745489297710155416879037996935949116083293651682502219904856662799569980641565511322314699627398144967416363096782138121951717342475666518502090307838007724087544054573626806950235770568603898880790885967640084182374949820595200000
472564360722335925183836608703809404949591105760929769647742439161148932459383403670785769537489500453469404921951727588258396700077297892313083802903588591954357552103874129247065122193623261574764912057410661668606762340089356677757167542701976001548528349550061145072268512078856897170949444297069835551437491268419182427256532746251529085508808422400000
376633795495701732371517777136936095744824111291461026409250724011435699170128572725616258321379131861415115722795526887841942169961606420173527790914160107787622969026787681009910902388317739475087634909756297349879589585051217272172462531533474873234177094591398732622598004126848947045246707104764658934495680540930088394523456598762468681150520312652800000
304696740556022701488557881703781301457562706034791970365083835725251480628634015335023552981995717675884828619741581252264131215498939593920383982849555527200186981942671233937017920032149051235345896641992844556052587974306434773187522188010581172446449269524441574691681785338620798159604586047754609078007005557612441511169476388398837163050770932936115200000
247109056590934410907220442061766635482083354594216287966082990773178950789822186436704101468398527035142596010610422395586210415769640010669431410090989532559351642355506370722921533146072880551865522176656196934958648847162518601055080494476581330854070357584322117074953927909621467307439319284728987962263681507223690065558445350991456939234175226611189427200000
202876535461157151354827982932710407730790434121851572420154135424779918598444015064534067305555190695852071324711156786776278751346874448759603187684702406231227698373870730363518578712925834933081593707034737683601050703520427771466221085965273272631191763576728458118537174813799224659407681132762499117018482517430649543823483633163986147111257861047786519731200000
166967388684532335565023429953620665562440527282283844101786853454593873006519424398111537392471921942686254700237282035516877412358477671329153423464510080328300395761695611089175790280737962149926151620889589113603664728997312055916699953749419903375470821423647521031556094871756761894692521572263536773306211111845424574566727030093960599072565219642328305738777600000
138082030442108241512274376571644290420138316062448739072177727806949132976391563977238241423574279446601532637096232243372457620020461034189209881205149836431504427294922270370748378562170294697988927390475690196950230730880777070243110861750770260091514369317356499893096890458942842086910715340261944911524236589496166123166683253887705415433011436644205508845969075200000
114470003236507732213675458177893116758294664015770004690835336351960831237428606537130502140143077661232670556152776529755767366996962197342854991519069214401717170227490562137350405828039174304632820806704347173271741275900164191231538904391388545615865412164088538411377322190463616090048983017077152331653592132692321716105180417472907789393966480978046366833308363340800000
96040332715429987327273709411252324960209223109231033935610847199295137408202600884652491295580042157774210596612179508465088820910451283570655337884499070883040705820864581633236990489724867241586936656824947278374990930480237756443261140784374989771711080805670283727145573317798973899551096751327730806257363799328857919812246370259769635301537877540580901773145716842931200000
81922403806261779190164474127798233191058467312174071947076052660998752209196818554608575075129775960581401638910189120720720764236614944885769003215477707463233722065197488133151152887735311757073656968271680028453867263699642806246101753089071866275269551927236752019255174040082524736317085528882554377737531320827515805599846153831583498912211809542115509212493296467020313600000
70207500061966344765970954327523085844737106486533179658644177130475930643281673501299548839386217998218261204546032076457657694950779007767104035755664395295991299809874247330110538024789162175812124021808829784384964244990593884952909202397334589397906006001641896480501684152350723699023742298252349101721064341949181045399068153833667058567765520777592991395106755072236408755200000
60308242553229090153969049767342330740629174471932001326775348155078824422578957537616312453032761260469486374705041553677127959962719167671942366714115715559256526536681978456564952163293890309022614534733784784786684286446920147174549004859310412292801259155410389076750946686869271657461394634198767878378394269734346517997799544143120003309710582347952379608396702607051075120716800000
52046013323436704802875289949216431429162977569277317145007125457833025476685640354962877646967272967785166741370450860823361429447826641700886262474281862527638382401156547408015553716922627336686516343475256269270908539203692087011635791193584885808687486651119165773236066990768181440389183569313536679040554254780741045032101006595512562856280232566282903602046354349885077829178598400000
45644353684653990112121629285462810363375931328256207136171249026519563343053306591302443696390298392747591232181885404942087973625743964771677252189945193436738861365814292076829640609741144174274074833227799748150586788881637960309204588876773944854218925793031508383128030750903695123221313990287971667518566081442709896493152582784264517624957763960630106458994652764849213256189630796800000
40212675596180165288779155400492735930134195500193718486966870392363735305229963106937452896519852884010627875552241041753979504764280432963847659179341715417766936863282391319686913377181948017535459928073691578120666961004723043032409242800437845416566873623660758885535795091546155403557977625443703039083856717751027418810467425432937040027587790049315123790374289085832156878703064731980800000
35507792551427085949991994218635085826308494626671053423991746556457178274518057423425770907627030096581384414112628839868763902706859622307077483055358734713888205250278351535283544512051660099483811116489069663480548926567170446997617361392786617502828549409692450095928107065835255221341694243266789783511045481774157210809642736657283406344360018613545254306900497262789794523894806158339046400000
1881913005225635555349575693587659548794350215213565831471562567492230448549457043441565858104232595118813373947969328513044486843463559982275106601934012939836074878264752631370027859138737985272641989173920692164469093108060033690873720153817690727649913118713699855084189674489268526731109794893139858526085410534030332172911065042836020536251080986517898478265726354927859109766424726391969459200000
1669256835635138737595073640212254019780588640894432892515275997365608407863368397532668916138454311870387462691848794391070459830152177704278019555915469477634598417020835584025214711056060592936833444397267653949884085586849249883804989776436291675425472936299051771459676241271981183210494388070215054512637759143684904637372114692995550215654708835041375950221699276821011030362818732309676910310400000
1514015949921070834998731791672514395940993897291250633511355329610606825932075136562130706937578060866441428661506856512700907065948025177780163737215330816214580764237897874710869742927846957793707934068321762132544865627272269644611125727227716549610903953223239956713926350833686933171918409979685054442962447543322208506096508026546964045598820913382527986851081244076657004539076590204876957651532800000
1379268530378095530683844662213660614702245440432329327128844705275262818424120449408101074020133613449328141510632746283070526337078650936957729164603166373571483076220724963861602335807268578550067927936241125302748372586445037646240735537504449776695533501386371600566386905609488796119617671491493084597538789711966531949053918812184284245540525852091482996021335013353834531135098773676642908420546380800000
1267547779417469792698453244574354104911363559757310651631408284147966530131766693006044887024502790759932562048271493834141813703775280211064153102270309897312192947046846241788812546606879823687512425773405594153225754406942989596895235958966589344783195287774075500920509566255120203633928640100682144745138147745297242861180551388397357221651743258072072873343606877272173934113155773008834832838482123955200000
21548312250096986475873705157764019783493180515874281077733940830515431012240033781102763079416547442918853554820615395180410832964179763588090602738595268254307280099796386110409813292316957002687711238147895100604837824918030823147219011302432018861314319892159283515648662626337043461776786881711596460667348511670053128640069373602755072768079635387225238846841316913626956879923648141150192158254196107238400000
20018382080340100436086672091562774378865164699247207121214831031548835410370991382644466900777972574471614952428351702122601663823723000373336169944155004208251463212710842696570716548562453055496883740239394548461894339348850634703766461499959345522161003179815974386037607579867113375990635013110073111959966767341479356506624448076959462601545981274732246888715583412759442941449069123128528515018148183624473600000
18757224009278674108613211749794319592996659323194633072578296676561258779517618925537865486028960302279903210425365544888877759002828451349815991237673238943131621030310059606686761406003018513000580064604312691908794995969873044717429174425461906754264859979487567999717238302335485233303225007284138505906488860998966157046707107848111016457648584454424115334726501657755598036137777768371431218572004848056131763200000
17650547792731232336205032256556454737009856423126149721296177172644144511526079408931131422353251644445388921010268977740433971221661572720176847754650517845486855389521766089892242483048840420733545840792658243086176091207650535079100853134359654255763233240697801487733921242497691604538334731854374334058006018200027153780951388485072466486647317971613092529977638059948017752005648880037516776676256562020819989171200000
16715068759716477022386165546958962635948334032700463786067479782494004852415197200257781456968529307289783308196724721920190970746913509366007474823654040399676052053877112487127953631447251878434667911230647356202608758373645056719908507918238592580207781878940818008884023416645313949497802991066092494352931699235425714630560964895363625762855010119117598625888823242770772811149349489395528387512414964233716529745126400000
15929460528009802602334015766251891392058762333163541988122308232716786624351682931845665728491008429847163492711478659989941995121808574425805123506942300500891277607344888200232939810769231040148238519402806930461086146730083739054072808046081378728938016130630599562466474316062984193871406250485986147118343909371360706042924599545281535352000824643519071490472048550360546489025330063393938553299331460914731852847105459200000
15403788330585479116456993245965578976120823176169145102514272061037132665748077395094758759450805151662207097451999864210273909282788891469753554431213204584361865446302506889625252797013846415823346648262514301755870303887990975665288405380560693230883061598319789776905080663632905715473649844219948604263438560362105802743508087760287244685384797430282942131286470948198648454887494171301938581040453522704545701703150979046400000
14957078468998500222079740441832577185813319304060239894541358171267055818441383150637010755426731802264003091625891868148175965913588013617130701352708021651415371348359734189826120465900444869764469595462901387004950065075239237370995041624524433127187452811968515873374833324387551449724913998737570094739798842111604734463946353215238914589508638304804736809479163290700887649695756840334182362190280370546113876353759600654054400000
14613065664211534716971906411670427910539612960066854376966906933327913534617231338172359508051916970811931020518496355180767918697575489303936695221595737153432817807347460303460119695184734637759886794767254655103836213578508734911462155667160371165262141397293240008287212157926637766381240976766605982560783468743037825571275587091288419553949939623794227862861142535014767233752754433006496167859903922023553257197623129839011148800000
14364643547919938626783384002672030636060439539745717852558469515461339004528738405423429396415034382308128193169681917142694864079716705985769771402828609621824459904622553478301297660366594148917968719256211325967070997947674086417967299020818644855452684993539254928146329551241884924352759880161573680857250149774406182536563902110736516421532790650189725989192503111919516190778957607645385733006285555349152851825263536631747959270400000
14235361755988659179142333546647982360335895583888006391885443289822186953487979759774618531847299072867355039431154779888410610302999255631897843460203152135228039765480950496996585981423294801577707000782905424033367358966145019640205593329631277051753610828597401633793012585280707960033585041240119517729534898426436526893734826991739887773738995534338018455289770583912240545061946989176577261409228985351010476158836164802062227636966400000
14192655670720693201604906546008038413254887897136342372709786959952720392627515820495294676251757175648752974312861315548745378472090257865002149929822542678822355646184507645505596223479024917172973879780556707761267256889246584581284976549642383220598349996111609428891633547524865836153484286116399159176346293731157217313053622510764668110417778547735004399923901272160503823426761148209047529625001298394957444730359656307656040954055500800000
14320389571757179440419350704922110758974181888210569454064175042592294876161163462879752328338022990229591751081677067388684086878339070185787169279190945562931756847000168214315146589490336141427530644698581718131118662201249803842516541338589164669583735146076613913751658249452589628678865644691446751608933410374737632268871105113361550123411538554664619439523216383609948357837601998542928957391626310080512061732932893214424945322642000307200000
14506554636190022773144802264086098198840846252757306856967009318145994709551258587897189108606417289102576443845738869264736980007757478098202402479820427855249869686011170401101243495153710511266088543079663280466823204809866051292469256375990823810288323702975609894630429806695473293851690898072435559379849544709609221488366429479835250275015888555875259492237018196596877686489490824523987033837717452111558718535461020826212469611836346311193600000
14782179174277633205834553507103734064618822331559695687249382495190768609032732501067235701669939217595525396278807907780766982627904870182068248126937015984499617210045382638722167121561631010980144225398176882795692845701253506267026172247134649462683801853332146482628407973022687286434873025135811835008066686059091796696645391639952120030241190438436889422589521542332218362532791150189942787480634083701678334187634780221910506534461236891106278400000
15092604936937463503157079130752912479975817600522449296681619527589774749822419883589647651405007941165031429600662873844163089263090872455891681337602693320174109171456335674135332631114425262210727254131538597334402395460979829898633721864324477101400161692252121558763604540456163719450005358663663883543236086466332724427274944864391114550876255437644064100463901494721194948145979764343931586017727399459413579205575110606570627171684922865819510246400000
15560475689982524871754948583806252766855067946138645224878749732945057767066914899980926728598563187341147403918283422933332145030246689502024323459068376813099506555771482080033527942678972445339259799009616293851768869720270204625491367242118535891543566704711937327085276281210304794752955524782237463933076405146789038884520468155187239101953419356211030087578282441057551991538505137038593465184276948842655400160947939035374316614007155474659915064038400000
16073971387751948192522861887071859108161285188361220517299748474132244673380123091680297310642315772523405268247586775890132105816244830255591126133217633247931790272111940988674634364787378536035455372376933631548877242421039121378132582361108447575964504405967431258879090398490244852979803057100051300242867926516633077167709643604308417992317882194965994080468365761612451207259275806560867049535358088154463028366259221023541669062269391605323692261151667200000
16700856271874274172031253500667661613379575310707308117474438664623402215641947892255828905757366087651818073709242660149847257943078378635559180052413120944601130092724306687232945105014086298940838131899634043179283454875459647111879753073191677031427120077800161077975374924031364402246015376326953300952339775650781767177250319704876446294018279600569667849606632026315336804342387563016740864467237053592487086472543330643459794155697897877931316259336582220800000
17519198229196113606460784922200377032435174500931966215230686159189948924208403338976364522139477025946757159320995550497189773582289219188701579874981363870886585467267797714907359415159776527588939200362716111295068344164357169820361860973778069205967048961612368970796168295308901257956070129766974012699004424657670073768935585370415392162425175300997581574237356995604788307755164553604561166826131669218518953709697953844989324069327094873949950756044074749619200000
18412677338885115400390284953232596261089368400479496492207451153308636319343031909264159112768590354270041774446366323572546452034985969367325360448605413428301801326098455398367634745332925130495975099581214632971116829716739385481200315883440750735471368458654599788306772878369655222111829706385089687346653650315211247531151300224306577162708859241348458234523462202380632511450677945838393786334264384348663420348892549491083779596862776712521398244602322561849779200000

36825354677770230800780569906465192522178736800958992984414902306617272638686063818528318225537180708540083548892732647145092904069971938734650720897210826856603602652196910796735269490665850260991950199162429265942233659433478770962400631766881501470942736917309199576613545756739310444223659412770179374693307300630422495062302600448613154325417718482696916469046924404761265022901355891676787572668528768697326840697785098982167559193725553425042796489204645123699558400000
39071701313114214879628184670759569266031639745817491556464211347320926269645913711458545637294948731761028645375189338620943571218240226997464414871940687294856422413980922355336120929596467126912459161311337451164709912658920975991107070304661273060670243869265060750786972047900408381321302636949160316549599045968878267261103059075978556739268199310141428373658786793451702189298338601069071614601309023587863777980349990020079780304542812183970407075046128476245231462400000
```

If what you want is, say, just one really enormous number that is highly composite, the least work is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number

https://oeis.org/A002201

https://oeis.org/A002201/b002201.txt

Note that entry 150 is about $2^{953}.$ It would be necessary to extend just a few more entries to reach $2^{1024}$

I have programmed SHC numbers, it is not a task for beginners, but is possible.

Guy Robin found a method for interpolating between consecutive Superior Highly Composite numbers, resulting in all the highly composite numbers between. The original is in French. Discussion in http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf

The reason for mentioning this is that you will need to compute such an enormous list yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the list, at this moment this is what I needed, I also want to know if you would like to share your SHC program? so other people (or me in the future) that may need larger lists and end in this page can make use of it, really really thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here is [a list of the first 10000 ones.](https://web.archive.org/web/19980707133953/www.math.princeton.edu/~kkedlaya/math/hcn10000.txt.gz)

I found this in the External Links section of the [highly composite number  Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number), which has at least one other link that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

Simplified the two programs, which previously allowed many, many choices....

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ date
Tue Jan  3 10:22:20 PST 2017
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$  ./Superior_Highly_Composite_construct_deltas  0.2 > temp.txt
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ cat temp.txt
1.0000000000000000           2           1
0.5849625007211562           2           2
0.4150374992788437           2           3
0.3219280948873623           2           4
0.2630344058337938           2           5
0.2223924213364480           2           6
0.6309297535714574           3           1
0.3690702464285426           3           2
0.2618595071429148           3           3
0.2031140135750123           3           4
0.4306765580733931           5           1
0.2519296364125923           5           2
0.3562071871080222           7           1
0.2083678469455574           7           2
0.2890648263178878          11           1
0.2702381544273197          13           1
0.2446505421182260          17           1
0.2354089133666382          19           1
0.2210647294575037          23           1
0.2058468324604344          29           1
0.2018490865820999          31           1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ sort -n -r temp.txt > Superior_Highly_Composite_Deltas.txt
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ cat Superior_Highly_Composite_Deltas.txt
1.0000000000000000           2           1
0.6309297535714574           3           1
0.5849625007211562           2           2
0.4306765580733931           5           1
0.4150374992788437           2           3
0.3690702464285426           3           2
0.3562071871080222           7           1
0.3219280948873623           2           4
0.2890648263178878          11           1
0.2702381544273197          13           1
0.2630344058337938           2           5
0.2618595071429148           3           3
0.2519296364125923           5           2
0.2446505421182260          17           1
0.2354089133666382          19           1
0.2223924213364480           2           6
0.2210647294575037          23           1
0.2083678469455574           7           2
0.2058468324604344          29           1
0.2031140135750123           3           4
0.2018490865820999          31           1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$   ./Superior_Highly_Composite_read > Superior_Highly_Composite_read.txt
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$  cat Superior_Highly_Composite_read.txt
2
6
12
60
120
360
2520
5040
55440
720720
1441440
4324320
21621600
367567200
6983776800
13967553600
321253732800
2248776129600
65214507758400
195643523275200
6064949221531200
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ date
Tue Jan  3 10:23:39 PST 2017
```

=================================================================

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;

//  g++  -o Superior_Highly_Composite_construct_deltas Superior_Highly_Composite_construct_deltas.cc  -lgmp -lgmpxx


//       ./Superior_Highly_Composite_construct_deltas


// save in temp.txt   then
// sort -n -r temp.txt > Superior_Highly_Composite_Deltas.txt


int PrimeQ(int i)
{
  if ( i < 0 ) i *= -1;
  if ( i <= 3) return 1;
  else
  {
    int boo = 1;
    int j = 2;

    while (boo && j * j   <= i )
    {
      if ( i %  j  == 0) boo = 0;
      ++j;
    }
    return boo;
  }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if ( argc != 2) cout << "Usage: ./Superior_Highly_Composite_construct_deltas LowerBound  " << endl;
  else {


   double bound = 0.5  ;


   bound = atof(argv[1]);




   for (int p = 2; p < 100100; ++p)
   {
      if( PrimeQ(p) )
      {    
        double eps = 1.0;
        for (int k = 1; k <= 500 && eps > bound; ++k)
        {

   double mu = (1.0 + k) / (1.0 * k) ;

          mu = log(mu);
          mu /=  log(1.0 * p);

  cout.precision(16);
  cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);  // DD page 582
        if ( mu > bound)         cout << mu <<   setw(12) << p <<   setw(12) << k << endl;
         eps = mu;


        }  // for k
      } // if prime
   }//  for p
   } // else argc 
    return 0 ;
}
```

=================================================================

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strstream>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;





const int SIZE = 80;


//  g++  -o Superior_Highly_Composite_read Superior_Highly_Composite_read.cc  -lgmp -lgmpxx 

//    ./Superior_Highly_Composite_read 


int main()
{




  char line[SIZE];

  ifstream ifs("Superior_Highly_Composite_Deltas.txt", ios::in );   // DD page 659
  if (!ifs)
  {
    cerr << "could not open file  for reading " << endl;
    exit(1);
  }


  int pp, kk;
  int  shc_count = 0;
   mpz_class n, sigma;
 n = 1; sigma = 1;
  double  delta_new;

  while(ifs.getline(  line,SIZE) && !ifs.eof()  ) // DD page 661
 {

          istrstream  lineBuffer(line, SIZE); // DD page 678


      lineBuffer >>  delta_new >> pp >> kk ;
     shc_count++ ;
     // if ( pp == 2 ) cout <<  endl;
      n *= pp;
      cout << n << endl;


  } // while not eof


    return 0 ;
}
```

=================================================================

Answer (score 0):

You can compute your (probably) own, if that is good enough.  If you look at the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) the number of divisors of a number $N$ that is $p^aq^br^c \ldots$ (with $p,q,r$ prime) is $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\ldots$.  Clearly you want $p=2, q=3, r=5$ and $a \ge b \ge c$ and so on.  Now if you increase $a$ by $1$, you multiply the number of factors by $\frac {a+2}{a+1}=1+\frac 1{a+1}$  If we consider $\Delta \frac {\log \sigma_0(N)}{\Delta \log N}$ for increasing the exponent on a prime $P$ that currently has exponent $A$, we get $ \frac {\Delta\log \sigma_0(N)}{\Delta \log N}\approx \frac{\frac 1{A+1}}{\log P}$  This expresses the ratio of the (log of) the additional factors we get to the increase in the (log of) $N$.  To have a highly composite number we want these ratios to be about the same.  They can't be absolutely the same because of the granularity of the primes and exponents.  You can pick a $k=\frac{\frac 1{A+1}}{\log P}$ and find $A=\frac 1{k \log P}-1$  If you pick $k=0.2$ and round all the numbers to the nearest integer, you get $2^6*3^4*5^2*7^2*11*13*17*19*23=6746328388800$, which is number $104$ on the list.  As you pick smaller positive $k$ you get bigger numbers.  Because of the granularity of integers, there will be other candidates.  If you really need the record setters, you should check around nearby exponents to find if the one you started with is really highly composite.